# Can I send transactions to nodeos via websocket? are there any 'API' available?

Tags: api

For some reason I need send transactions to nodeos via WebSocket
I tried to find relevant information from the developer documentation, but did not find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the nodeos can create unix socket file，so i sugesst use http over unix socket to kepp connect alive

Answer (score 1):

No, websocket APIs are not supported in nodeos. There are some third party services supporting websocket APIs, but they are usually related to read-only APIs, not for sending transaction.

Comment: dose http api support keepalive？

Comment: I don't think so.